# iOS static library + preprocessed headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor, static-libraries

I'm building a static library for iOS (.a file), and I have multiple headers that should be publicly accessible. I currently have 3 headers and a 4th header that #imports all 3, but this still means that when I distribute it, I have multiple header files.

Is there any way to have Xcode automatically copy and paste the contents of a header where the #import statement is when the framework/library compiles, so the 1 header sitting next to the library contains the contents of 3 other headers instead of 3 #import statements? (i.e. Run the preprocessor on a header it doesn't compile)

I could always copy and paste manually every time, but I'm too lazy ;P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a "Run Script Build Phase" to your library target, so that each time you build the library a shell script could append the three files in one general file.

Have a look to [this](http://yeahrightkeller.com/2008/xcode-run-script-build-phase-tip/) for more info about Xcode 3.x.

In Xcode 4, it is similar. You select your target, then the Build Phases tab, and there you can put your script under "Run Script".

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is not to have three header files in the first place but just a single one with the public API.

This might not be the way you're used to organize your code but it works. If the users of your static library can work with a single file, so can your static library project. It saves you the trouble a manual merging or fiddling with XCode, shell scripts and build phases.